Under what circumstances can a 4D singularity occur in General Relativity?
I've tried to find on the literature about 4D (single point) singularities, but most of the theorems about singularities pertain to either space-like or time-like singularities, which always have some extent in space and time.
I am wondering if it is possible to have a physical singularity that occurs at a single point and time, or any such singularities are always bound to be mild in some rigurous sense (tidal forces remain bounded near the event for example)

Hi UnkemptPanda. What is your definition of a 4D singularity?

@Qmechanic I think anything that has measure 0 and exists only for an instant. A spacelike singularity of zero extent, or a timelike singularity of zero duration

Can't you just write down a metric with precisely what you want, i.e. a pole in the Ricci tensor $R$ and use that to calculate which matter distribution you need? Of course, you need to deduce which metric this Ricci tensor has or you start with the metric and hope that the singularity is not a coordinate singularity by calculating the Ricci tensor.
